# I have used TER to break the long bonds of a chain in my PDB

Tags: rna, pdb

I’m now not sure what I need to alter in my PDB to get it to work in leap. I know breaking the bonds turns the formerly connected residues into terminal residues.
It keeps saying that 3 of my atoms no longer have a type , how can I fix this ?

Comment: For the rest of us could you explain `leap` please?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you have three options in a PDB:

- Add a `TER` record
- Add the  `OXT` atom, if your chain was cleaved or cleaved spontaneously (*i.e.* Asp-Pro sequence), the C-terminal would sill have a terminal oxygen. i.e. making it a terminal residue. If you have protons, you'll need to add also `3H` .
- Assign a different chain

If you are using forcefields as is your case, the second is the only choice. The `C`  atom and the `N`  atoms have a type that does not match because they have the wrong number of bonds —hence the type error.